# Rails 3 Polymorphic nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, polymorphic-associations

I am trying to build a polymorphic relationship from a nested form that's backwards to all the examples I've found. I am hoping someone to point out the error of my ways.

```
class Container < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :content, :polymorphic => true
end
class Notice < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_one :container, :as => :content
end
class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_one :container, :as => :content
end
```

It seems most people would build a Container *from* a Notice or Form, but in my case the notice or form contains a small amount of content (file location or a couple db fields) so it's much dry'er to build the Notice or Form from the Container.

I thought I could solve by adding `accepts_nested_attributes_for :content` but that gives me an `unrecognized attribute :notice` when I try to create a Container with a nested Notice (looking for content, not the polymorphic association)

I can do it manually and explicitly exclude the nested fields like

```
 if params[:container].has_key('notice')   
     @c = Container.new(params[:container].except(:notice))
```

and then build, but isn't that a smell? Is there a better way?

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested attributes are designed to work from the parent down to the children, not the other way around.  Moreover, in this scenario, how would nested attributes know whether you are trying to create a `Notice` or `Form` object?

If you find it DRYer to build the content from the container, you probably have your associations inside out - try changing your schema to:

```
class Container < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :notice
  has_one :form
end

class Notice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :container
end

class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :container
end
```

You can use validation to ensure only one child (`:notice` or `:form`) is actually associated if need be.

Comment: Hmm. I was thinking it would know what object to create the same way I do, by the simple_fields_for key. If I do the has_one you mention, I lose the ability to do a Container.find(1).content.get_data where get_data has been defined on Notice and Form.

Comment: Then you could change this to use STI and have Notice and Form inherit from an abstract Content class.  Alternatively, you can create a helper method and/or cache in the Container model to find the content.

Comment: +1 for abstract_class. I went with STI, but will look into the .abstract_class = true to remove the duplicated fields. Thanks!